# JTable Cell Editor function not working with second row

Tags: java, swing

i have table in jinternalframe, which works like whenever user presses enter next cell is selected in editing mode after previous editing is stopped, if it is the last column then selection goes to next row with column no.-1,but the problem is when i load the class it works with first row in second row its not working .Need help i m unable to find proper information on google about cell editor i need to work with only editingstop and editing cancel method..

```
table.getDefaultEditor(String.class).addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {

        @Override
        public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {

            if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 1
                    && table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString().isEmpty()) {

                main = new MainWindow();
                main.itemdata.setSize(getDesktopPane().getWidth(), getDesktopPane().getHeight());
                main.itemdata.setLocation(0, 0);
                main.itemdata.show();
                getDesktopPane().add(main.itemdata);
                main.itemdata.moveToFront();
                main.itemdata.searchField.grabFocus();
                main.itemdata.searchField.selectAll();

            }

            else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 5) {

                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow(), 7, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());

            }

            else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 7) {

                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow(), 8, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());

            }

            else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 8) {

                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, 1, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Editing Cancelled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont really know, what you are doing with your code, but `table.changeSelection(getRow(), 8, false, false);` seems to be diffrent from the other. Is that wanted?

Comment: oops srry for that mistake.. i rewrote the code now can anyone help me.. i m stuck at this.

Comment: guys help me with this code...

Comment: Does a error is thrown?

Comment: nope only stuck at next row

Comment: i think the code is working for only one time as class loaded but after the if condition is over its not working for second row

Comment: what are you doing in the first `if`

Comment: actually i m making billing app, i want every column no 1 to open ItemDatabase frame and after selection of item move it to specific column for other details, it is working in first row but soon after it jumps to the next row it is like the code is dead

Comment: Did you debug at  `else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 8) { ` ? Pls make a breakpoint at look what is happening.

Comment: debugging doesn't help..it is not showing any kind of error

Comment: Sorry I dont know...

Comment: i made it working by using actionmap but i have to press enter twice in order to start editing mode

Comment: is there is any way to press enter only once to start editing

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 1) {
                ItemData itemdata = null;
                if (itemdata == null) {
                    itemdata = new ItemData();
                    itemdata.setSize(getDesktopPane().getWidth(), getDesktopPane().getHeight());
                    itemdata.setLocation(0, 0);
                    itemdata.setVisible(true);
                    getDesktopPane().add(itemdata);
                    itemdata.moveToFront();
                    itemdata.searchField.grabFocus();
                    itemdata.searchField.selectAll();
                    System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + "+" + table.getSelectedColumn());

                }

                if (itemdata != null) {
                    itemdata.show();
                }

            } else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 3) {
                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow(), 5, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + "+" + table.getSelectedColumn());
            }

            else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 5) {
                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow(), 7, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + "+" + table.getSelectedColumn());
            } else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 7) {
                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn() + 1, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + "+" + table.getSelectedColumn());
            } else if (table.getSelectedColumn() == 8) {
                table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, 1, false, false);
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + "+" + table.getSelectedColumn());

            }
```

Comment: the problem was accessing itemdata frame from main window frame class, which was making table class to  lose focus when pressing enter. Solved the problem by creating instance of class inside the table class.now its working thanks @Wulf for trying to help. :)